# SQL Server 100% CPU Utilization - One database shows high CPU usage than others

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, cpu-usage, sql-server-performance

We have an SQL server with about 40 different (about 1-5GB each) databases. The server is  an 8 core 2.3G CPU with 32Gigs of RAM. 27Gig is pinned to SQL Server. The CPU utliziation is mostly close to 100% always and memory consumption is about 95%. The problem here is the CPU which is constantly close to 100% and trying to understand the reason.

I have run an initial check to see which database contributes to high CPU by using - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319575/sql-server-2008-high-cpu-usage) script but I could not substantiate in detail on whats really consuming CPU. The top query (from all DBs) only takes about 4 seconds to complete. IO is also not a bottleneck.

Would Memory be the culprit here? I have checked the memory split and the OBJECT CACHE occupies about 80% of memory allocated (27G) to SQL Server. I hope that is normal provided there are lot of SPs involved. Running profiler, I do see lot of recompiles, but mostly are due to "temp table changed", "deferred compile" etc and am not clear if these recompiles are a result of plans getting thrown out of cache due to memory pressure

Appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: I assume you have checked the sql server executable and made sure it is using the CPU cycles.

Comment: Yes, I have checked and it is the SQL Server process that takes all the CPU

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can see some reports in SSMS:

Right-click the instance name / reports / standard / top sessions

You can see top CPU consuming sessions.  This may shed some light on what SQL processes are using resources.  There are a few other CPU related reports if you look around.  I was going to point to some more DMVs but if you've looked into that already I'll skip it.

You can use [sp_BlitzCache](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/05/introducing-sp_blitzcache/) to find the top CPU consuming queries.  You can also sort by IO and other things as well.  This is using DMV info which accumulates between restarts.

[This article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2454/how-to-find-out-how-much-cpu-a-sql-server-process-is-really-using/) looks promising.

Some [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952/cpu-utilization-by-database) goodness from Mr. Ozar.

edit:
A little more advice...
A query running for 'only' 5 seconds can be a problem.  It could be using all your cores and really running 8 cores times 5 seconds - 40 seconds of 'virtual' time.  I like to use some DMVs to see how many executions have happened for that code to see what that 5 seconds adds up to.

Comment: Thanks Sam and I will check the article and links. To your point on reports, I did check many of those Reports on various aspects of CPU, IO and Memory and I see the top queries taking not more than 5 seconds. That puzzles me. I have monitored this behavior for more than a week and there has been no change

Comment: Thanks. These SSMS reports helped me find the deadlocked transactions that were causing entire queries to freeze on one of the tables. I was able to find the culprit session and terminate it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://sqlserverstudymaterials.blogspot.in/2016/03/troubleshooting-high-cpu-utilization.html) article on sqlserverstudymaterial;

> Remember that "%Privileged time" is not based on 100%.It is based on number of processors.If you see 200 for sqlserver.exe and the system has 8 CPU then CPU consumed by sqlserver.exe is 200 out of 800 (only 25%).
>
> If "% Privileged Time" value is more than 30% then it's generally caused by faulty drivers or anti-virus software. In such situations make sure the BIOS and filter drives are up to date and then try disabling the anti-virus software temporarily to see the change.
>
> If "% User Time" is high then there is something consuming of SQL Server.
> There are several known patterns which can be caused high CPU for processes running in SQL Server including

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do not copy content from elsewhere without **clear** attribution. It is seen as plagiarism. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing