# Will Partitioned tables work same with Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, database-design, database-administration

I have a database with a Table `MonitoringRecords`, I am inserting data using Entity Framework.

No the Problem is that I now have about 300,000 records in this table.

And now the SQL-server CPU Utilization is about 98% with 3.6 GB RAM Utilization.

I ran the script I found here: [SQL Server 2008 High CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319575/sql-server-2008-high-cpu-usage)

and found out the Inserting data to the Table `MonitoringRecords`, is using up all the CPU.

So I looked for a solution, And I found Table partitioning.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx

I want to Partition my Table with Respect to Date.

1. So I want to ask is that will this affect any part of my code?
2. Will i have to re-code my Entity Framework Insertion code?
3. Will this increase the performance?

Any other tips on how to solve this problem I am having?

Answer (score 2):

If you partition you database files it shouldn't affect any of your code.

It might improve performance a bit, but it sounds like there may be something else at play causing your issue.

The key is to work out what is causing the ramp up in cpu usage
- Is it happening whilst running specific queries
- When inserting data

It might be that you need to apply some indexes to the tables to improve the querying.

Also, if the entity framework queries are complicated, they are often not the most efficient way of retrieving the data, so you might want to plug in a stored procedure or something.

Comment: This insert statement is executed sometimes twice or three times a minute. As it is a real time system. Receiving a storing devices data to MonitoringLog Table.
I have already tried using indexing. but not that much effect on performance

Comment: and Also I am getting SQL-Timeout issue in the function that inserts data to the MonitoringLog table.

Comment: Ok, do the issue is with the inserting - I don't think the partitioning is going to help this. Could you post the function that you're getting the timeout error with?